# Can I concatenate a bash alias?

Tags: ssh, alias, bashrc

Sample : to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) locally, I must write :

```
php composer.phar
```

After some locals installation of Composer, I want to alias it only "composer" but keeping absolute path with "pwd" command. I tried something like this in my .bashrc file :

```
alias composer='php ' . pwd . '/composer.phar'
```

Tested with this signs : ".", "+", ";", "&&" and “nothing” but none works.

And nothing found in [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29), [official documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/alias.html) or other stack question.

Comment: Presumably you want something like `alias composer=/path/to/composer.phar`. The alias is defined, and just copied verbatim when used (no further expansion). Or use a shell function, that can take arguments and do other stuff.

Comment: Do you want a *relative* or *absolute* path? Because a relative path is easy, and your attempted solution seems to be trying for an absolute path.

Comment: You're right, I meant absolute path ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a subshell to your alias.

```
alias composer='php $(pwd)/composer.phar'
```

Comment: +1 Well done! I'm more a shell functions than an aliases guy, but anyway, I never though about embedding a to be substituted command inside an alias definition which I wrongly thought were more static than what you demonstrate.

Comment: I'm the same way, preferring functions. With an alias just remember its just text substitution so all subshells are evaluated at run time and not when the alias is created.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a shell function:

```
composer() {
    php "$PWD"/composer.phar "$@"
}
```

Comment: better double-quote `$PWD` too